# channel ID not supported for array print

Tags: tcl

why does parray have no channelId just like puts command,

> puts ?channelId? string

parray prints on stdout channelId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To introspect what `parray` does, you'll want to read the [`info`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm) documentation, particularly `info body`, `info args` and `info default`.

To add an optional leading argument, you'll need to do some checking based on the number of arguments received, something like:

```
proc parray {args} {
    set chan stdout
    set pattern *

    switch [llength $args] {
        1 { set a [lindex $args 0] }
        2 {
            if {[lindex $args 0] in [chan names]} {
                lassign $args chan a
            } else {
                lassign $args a pattern
            }
        }
        3 { lassign $args chan a pattern }
        default {
            error {wrong # args: should be "parray ?channelId? a ?pattern?"}
        }
    }

    upvar 1 $a array
    if {![array exists array]} {
        error "\"$a\" isn't an array"
    }
    set maxl 0
    set names [lsort [array names array $pattern]]
    foreach name $names {
        if {[string length $name] > $maxl} {
            set maxl [string length $name]
        }
    }
    set maxl [expr {$maxl + [string length $a] + 2}]
    foreach name $names {
        set nameString [format %s(%s) $a $name]
        puts $chan [format "%-*s = %s" $maxl $nameString $array($name)]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`parray` is meant to be written only on `stdout`, not specific to any channel like `puts` command.

Quoting the man page from [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/library.htm#M13)

> parray arrayName
>
> Prints on standard output the names and values of all
> the elements in the array arrayName. ArrayName must be an array
> accessible to the caller of parray. It may be either local or global.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, `parray` has no option to change the channel because it is a *simple* helper procedure. It does not need to handle complex cases because in virtually all of those you're better off rewriting it from scratch anyway.

It's not for writing out computer-readable versions of arrays; a simple `puts $fd [array get theAry]` is far better for that. It's not for producing *real* tabular output (there are libraries for creating HTML tables and CSV files from arrays, but `parray` does neither). It's just a simple interactive debugging tool.

Plus it's a bit awkward to do optional arguments before mandatory ones with Tcl's procedures — the actual-to-formal argument mapper is not the most sophisticated — and there's already an optional argument after the array name, a glob pattern to filter the results by.

---

The *entire* definition of `parray` is this (the contents of `parray.tcl` in your Tcl installation):

```
# parray:
# Print the contents of a global array on stdout.
#
# Copyright (c) 1991-1993 The Regents of the University of California.
# Copyright (c) 1994 Sun Microsystems, Inc.
#
# See the file "license.terms" for information on usage and redistribution
# of this file, and for a DISCLAIMER OF ALL WARRANTIES.
#

proc parray {a {pattern *}} {
    upvar 1 $a array
    if {![array exists array]} {
        return -code error "\"$a\" isn't an array"
    }
    set maxl 0
    set names [lsort [array names array $pattern]]
    foreach name $names {
        if {[string length $name] > $maxl} {
            set maxl [string length $name]
        }
    }
    set maxl [expr {$maxl + [string length $a] + 2}]
    foreach name $names {
        set nameString [format %s(%s) $a $name]
        puts stdout [format "%-*s = %s" $maxl $nameString $array($name)]
    }
}
```

<sup>The license is exactly Tcl's license. Hack away if you want.</sup>